# FragmentPagerAdapter - how to detect a swipe or a tab click when user goes to a new tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, android-pageradapter

I have a `MainActivity` that has three fragments in a `FragmentPagerAdapter` as below. How can I find out when an user goes from 1st fragment to second or from second to third, either with swiping or with a click on the tab? I saw that the `getItem()` method is not called always as I have declared `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`;

```
public class MainThreeTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] CONTENT = new String[]{"News", "Rewards", "Me"};

    public MainThreeTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return NewsFragment.newInstance();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return RewardsFragment.newInstance();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return MeFragment.newInstance(true, App.getAccountData().getId());
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }
}
```

#### In the MainActivity's `onCreate()`

```
    mainThreeTabAdapter = new MainThreeTabAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    // this ensures that 2 tabs on each side of current are kept in memory, which is all we need for our case. Default = 1
    // this is all taken from the Quickreturn facebook sample app
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mainThreeTabAdapter);
```

Answer (score 32):

The `getItem()` method is only called when creating a view. To understand why `getItem()` isn't being called, it helps to understand the default behavior of a `ViewPager`. By default, when you are on a particular page of a `ViewPager` it also creates the pages that are before and after this particular page. If you were to have 3 fragments named and in this order [a,b,c], and you were on page b, due to the default behavior of the ViewPager fragments a and c would already be created with a call to `getItem(int)`. Because the fragments are already created, you won't get another call to `getItem()`

Aside: this behavior can be modified with [`ViewPager.setOffScreenLimit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

What you actually want to do in order to be notified when a user switches pages is to set a [`OnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) to the `ViewPager` using [`ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)) to be notified when a page is selected.

Comment: `setOnPageChangeListener()` is now deprecated. `addOnPageChangeListener()` should be used instead

Comment: Why is this not an accepted answer? I feel like it answers the question. I had the same question and this answer answered it for me. With the method `onPageSelected(int position)` I can check which fragment is being displayed, with an `if` statement

Answer (score 4):

```
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            _position = position;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    _header.setButtonVisible(1, View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    _header.setButtonVisible(1, View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    _header.setButtonVisible(1, View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    _header.setButtonVisible(1, View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

If as I assume you are using a TabLayout with your ViewPager you should use addOnTabSelectedListener().  This will handle both an explicit tab click or a swipe.

```
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "tabSelected: " + tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "tabUnselected: " + tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "tabReselected: " + tab.getPosition());
        }
});
```

Comment: but addOnTabSelectedListener is called from tabclick and swipe.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I guess you have following declared fields

```
ViewPager pager;
TabLayout tabs;
MainThreeTabAdapter adapter;
```

Next you have to create your adapter instance and set it to pager. Here you can add listener calling `addOnPageChangeListener`

```
adapter = new MainThreeTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(/*here is your listener instance*/);
tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```

Always when page switches to new one by swiping or clicking on tab the method `onPageSelected(int position)` will be called.

If you want to get actual instance of current fragment to interact with it directly, you can create your own `FragmentPagerAdapter` which should cache created fragments:

```
public abstract class CachingFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();

    public CachingFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }

    public SparseArray<Fragment> getRegisteredFragments() {
        return registeredFragments;
    }
}
```

In this way you have to

1. extend your `MainThreeTabAdapter` from `CachingFragmentPagerAdapter`
2. add `addOnPageChangeListener` to `ViewPager`
3. find and interact with fragment in `onPageSelected` method like as following:

   ```
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       final Fragment fragment = adapter.getRegisteredFragment(position);
       if (fragment instanceof NewsFragment) {
           //...
       } else ...
   }
   ```